# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64' - multiply column by value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having problems creating a new column in my dataframe by multiplying an existing column by a value - I have looked over similar questions but have been unable to understand how to fix my code below:

```
list = []

i = 1
for col in df.columns[1:19]:

    #calculations
    x = df[[df.columns[i], df.columns[i+1], df.columns[i+2]]].values
    Q = np.cov(x.T)

    eval, evec = np.linalg.eig(Q)

    w = np.array([2*(evec[0,2]/evec[1,2]),2*(evec[1,2]/evec[1,2]),2*(evec[2,2]/evec[1,2])])

    #create new columns in dataframe with applied weights
    df['w1_PCA'] = df.columns[i] * w[0]
    df['b_PCA'] = df.columns[i+1] * w[1]
    df['w2_PCA'] = df.columns[i+2] * w[2]

    i = i + 1

print(x)
```

Receiving the error as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-d7d86010b8f8> in <module>
 19 
 20     #create new columns in dataframe for back-applied PCA weights
---> 21     df['w1_PCA'] = df.columns[i] * w[0]
 22     df['b_PCA'] = df.columns[i+1] * w[1]
 23     df['w2_PCA'] = df.columns[i+2] * w[2]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'
```

Could someone please advise me as to where I am going wrong with this?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is thrown because the column number i of your data frame df is either a string (in my case with your code) or an integer. You first need to convert the int to a float by using `float()`.
I created a short example of your problem and could get rid of the errors as I understand it, while adding three further columns with some values inserted. I hope you can apply this solution to your data frame or data set. Below you can find two examples, depending on what you want to precisely do.

Solution 1:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [2,3,4], 'c': [2,3,4], 'd': [2,3,4], 'e': [2,3,4], 'f': [2,3,4], 'g': [2,3,4]})

list = []

i = 1
for col in df.columns[1:5]:

    #calculations
    x = df[[df.columns[i], df.columns[i+1], df.columns[i+2]]].values
    Q = np.cov(x.T)

    eval, evec = np.linalg.eig(Q)

    w = np.array([2*(evec[0,2]/evec[1,2]),2*(evec[1,2]/evec[1,2]),2*(evec[2,2]/evec[1,2])])

    #create new columns in dataframe with applied weights
    df['w1_PCA'] = float(df['a'][0]) * w[0]
    df['b_PCA'] = float(df['b'][0]) * w[1]
    df['w2_PCA'] = df['c'][0] * w[2]
    i = i + 1
```

The resulting `df` in this case is:

```
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   w1_PCA  b_PCA   w2_PCA
0   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   -0.0    4.0     -4.0
1   2   3   3   3   3   3   3   -0.0    4.0     -4.0
2   3   4   4   4   4   4   4   -0.0    4.0     -4.0
```

Alternatively you could apply a function on the column `df['a']` and store the results in new columnns. You will have to change lines 21 to 23 of your code with the below standing three lines.
Here is the mapping of the function to the whole column:

Solution 2

```
    df['w1_PCA'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: float(x) * w[0])
    df['b_PCA'] = df['b'].apply(lambda x: float(x) * w[1])
    df['w2_PCA'] = df['c'].apply(lambda x: float(x) * w[2])
```

Result:

```
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   w1_PCA  b_PCA   w2_PCA
0   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   -0.0    4.0     -4.0
1   2   3   3   3   3   3   3   -0.0    6.0     -6.0
2   3   4   4   4   4   4   4   -0.0    8.0     -8.0
```